# Regarding the data amount limit of Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

・ Maximum number of records per table
・ Maximum capacity limit per table
・ Limitation on the number of tables that can be created with Snowflake
Are there any restrictions such as?

Answer (score 3):

There are no limits like that as of now.

For more read [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-lifecycle.html#organizing-data).

Answer (score 1):

I've used Snowflake extensively. In a previous position, we had more than 50 Petabytes of data in Snowflake, spread out over more than 10,000 tables (I don't have the exact number, I just stopped counting at 10,000).

In my current position, we have a single table with more than 100 TB of data - that is the compressed size on Snowflake. We can run text search queries on this table in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake scales really well and has no "limits" on things like this, per se. Just be aware that with the pay-for-what-you-use pricing model, your budget can be the limiting factor.

I've heard a horror story about a company that shifted their entire process into Snowflake with no apparent problems, but their first month's bill exceeded their entire project's budget. Find ways to learn from mistakes while they're small, and impose your own limits while you figure out how to optimize things for cost.